# Which path should I use for the JSON files containing my account credentials when deploying spiders to Scrapy Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, scrapy

I want to use Scrapy Cloud to deploy a scraper. I run my spider from a `main.py` file using `CrawlerProcess`. I then do some operations on the crawled data using `pandas`. Finally, I publish the cleaned data to a table on **Google BigQuery** and send an **E-mail notification**.

The problem I am facing is with the **last two steps**. To interact with **GCP** or **Gmail**, I need two JSON files containing my account's credentials. My problem is with the path to these two JSON files. On my local computer, the JSON files live under the project's directory, so I simply refer to them using `os.getcwd() + "/credentials.json"`

When I deploy them to Scrapy Cloud, I get the **error shown in the screenshot below**

[image: Error message on Scrapy Cloud]

I followed the steps shown in Scrapy Cloud's [documentation](https://support.zyte.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200416-deploying-non-code-files), but I still get the same error.

Here is a screenshot of my **project tree** below

[image: Project Tree]

My **setup.py file**

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name         = 'project',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    scripts      = ['main_scraper_1.py'],
    package_data = {'indeed': ['*.json']},
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = indeed.settings']},
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

... and a **code snippet** showing the exact line where the pipeline fails. My dilemma is how to refer to these JSON files in my scripts. Which path should I give?

```py
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import yagmail
from datetime import datetime

# Upload the results to bigquery
# First, set the credentials
key_path_local = os.getcwd() + "/bq_credentials.json" # <-- This works locally but does not work on Scrapy Cloud
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path_local, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)

# Now, instantiate the client and upload the table to BigQuery
client = bigquery.Client(project="web-scraping-371310", credentials=credentials)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("job_title_name", "STRING"), 
        bigquery.SchemaField("job_type", "STRING"), 
        bigquery.SchemaField("company_name", "STRING"), 
        bigquery.SchemaField("company_indeed_url", "STRING"), 
        bigquery.SchemaField("city", "STRING"), 
        bigquery.SchemaField("remote", "STRING"), 
        bigquery.SchemaField("salary", "STRING"), 
        bigquery.SchemaField("crawled_page_rank", "INT64"),  
        bigquery.SchemaField("job_page_url", "STRING"), 
        bigquery.SchemaField("listing_page_url", "STRING"), 
        bigquery.SchemaField("job_description", "STRING"), 
        bigquery.SchemaField("crawled_timestamp", "TIMESTAMP"), 
        bigquery.SchemaField("salary_type", "STRING"), 
        bigquery.SchemaField("salary_low", "FLOAT64"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("salary_high", "FLOAT64"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("crawler_name", "STRING"),
    ]
)
job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND

# Upload the table
client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=df,
    destination="web-scraping-371310.crawled_datasets.chris_indeed_workflow",
    job_config=job_config
).result()

# Step 16: Send success E-mail
yag = yagmail.SMTP("omarmoataz6@gmail.com", oauth2_file=os.getcwd() + "/email_authentication.json") # <-- This works locally but does not work on Scrapy Cloud
contents = [
    f"This is an automatic notification to inform you that the Indeed crawler ran successfully"
]
yag.send(["omarmoataz6@gmail.com"], f"The Indeed crawler ran successfully at {datetime.now()} CET", contents)
```

Would appreciate any insights as I couldn't find any solution online. Thank you, guys!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file called `MANIFEST.in` in the same directory as your `setup.py` file.

Inside of it write:

```
include *.json
```

You can also remove the `package_data` line from your setup.py file, since it isn't doing anything.

Then repackage your project and reinstall in google cloud.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @Alexander. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I am not sure why. Yesterday, I tried deploying my code to a normal VM on Google cloud and it worked fine. I think it's best to use a normal VM instead of Scrapy cloud for this use case. It's a pity because I really wanted to use scrapy cloud, but I can't figure out why the JSON files are not being detected.

Comment: How are you transferring the package to the cloud? @oelmaria

Answer (score 0):

Following the support article [Deploying non-code files](https://scrapinghub.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/22000200416) from Zyte (Scrapy cloud), I was able to successfully authenticate with the Google cloud API.

Note my placement of the `credentials` file and the matching configuration in the `setup.py` file.

[image: setup.py]

With the above configuration allowing me to read the credentials file in Zyte cloud, I am able to authenticate with Google Cloud using the following method:

```
data = pkgutil.get_data("contractor", "resources/pipedrive-automations-381a9162f013.json")
data_str = data.decode('utf-8')

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    json.loads(
        data_str,
        strict=False # set strict flag to false if the JSON string contains control characters that will fail the JSON parser.
    ),
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
)

service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
```